# LabVIEW to TRNSYS communication through type 62 error

Tags: labview

I am trying to transfer data from TRNSYS (heating simulation program) to LabVIEW 2013 32 bit in real time through type 62 (in TRNSYS). Type 62 is an Excel file that transfers real time data from TRNYS to LabVIEW (and other way round). My LabVIEW program works on two different Windows 10 PCs and is not working on a Windows 7 although Excel versions are the same. It says there is an

> Error 14012 occured at DDE Request

I have not attached the TRNSYS file but I can send it if you need to.

Do you have any recommendation?

Thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHcWk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9fQV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Error 14012 is "Transaction Failed Error" Did you try troubleshooting your excel? also what's your excel version?

Here's a link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3001579/an-error-occurred-when-sending-commands-to-the-program-error-in-excel

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look at the link. The Excel version is 2016.